# Is there a way to get method meta data when using @BeforeMethod in TestNG?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I am using TestNG and have a suite of tests.  I want to perform an action before every test method that requires information about the method.  As a simple example, say I want to print the name of the method before its executed. I can write a method annotated with `@BeforeMethod`.  How can I inject parameters into that method?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Take a look at the [dependency injection](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependency-injection) section in the documentation. It states that dependency injection can be used for example in this case:

> Any `@BeforeMethod` (and `@AfterMethod`) can declare a parameter of type `java.lang.reflect.Method`. This parameter will receive the test method that will be called once this `@BeforeMethod` finishes (or after the method as run for `@AfterMethod`).

So basically you just have to declare a parameter of type `java.lang.reflect.Method` in your `@BeforeMethod` and you will have access to the name of the following test name. Something like:

```
@BeforeMethod
protected void startTest(Method method) throws Exception {
    String testName = method.getName(); 
    System.out.println("Executing test: " + testName);
}
```

There's also a way by using the `ITestNGMethod` interface ([documentation](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/ITestNGMethod.html)), but as I'm not exactly sure on how to use it, I'll just let you have a look at it if you're interested.

Comment: I'm running my testcase using data provide with multiple dataset , so in the extent report it's showing the same method is running multiple time as many time as manydata we have in excel sheet , so I want to pass the testcase name as a variable (That's in excel) to before method that is in AbstractBaseTestCase class , is there any way to achieve this  ??

Answer (score 6):

Below example shows how to get params when using data provider, using Object[] array in @BeforeMethod.

```
public class TestClass {

   @BeforeMethod
       public  void  beforemethod(Method method, Object[] params){
             String classname = getClass().getSimpleName();
             String methodName = method.getName();
             String paramsList = Arrays.asList(params).toString();   
       }

   @Test(dataProvider = "name", dataProviderClass = DataProvider.class)
       public void exampleTest(){...}
}

public class DataProvider {

   @DataProvider(name = "name")
   public static Object[][] name() {
       return new Object[][]{
               {"param1", "param2"},
               {"param1", "param2"}
       };
   }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, to get parameters when using a data provider. Works perfectly.

Comment: This nailed it!

Answer (score 2):

Below example explains how you can get the method name and class name in your before Method

```
@BeforeMethod
        public  void  beforemethod(Method method){
//if you want to get the class name in before method
      String classname = getClass().getSimpleName();
//IF you want to get the method name in the before method 
      String methodName = method.getName()      
        }

@Test
public void exampleTest(){


}
```