# Get the name of currently executing @Test method name in @BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod in testng

Tags: automation, annotations, testng

I want to Print the name of Currently Executing Test Method in  `@BeforeMethod` and `@AfterMethod` using **testng**.
Like :

```
public class LoginTest {

@Test
public void Test01_LoginPage(){
    //Some Code here
}


@Test
public void Test02_LoginPage(){
    //Some Code Here
}

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeTestCase(){
    //Print Test method name which is going to execute.
}

@AfterMethod
public void AfterTestCase(){
    //Print Test method name which is executed.
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get method meta data when using @BeforeMethod in testng?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477702/is-there-a-way-to-get-method-meta-data-when-using-beforemethod-in-testng)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use listeners like this [link](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-listeners/). Important code from the link:-

`// This belongs to IInvokedMethodListener and will execute before every method including //@Before @After @Test`

```
public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod arg0, ITestResult arg1) {

    String textMsg = "About to begin executing following method : " + returnMethodName(arg0.getTestMethod());

    Reporter.log(textMsg, true);

}

// This belongs to IInvokedMethodListener and will execute after every method including @Before @After @Test

public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod arg0, ITestResult arg1) {

    String textMsg = "Completed executing following method : " + returnMethodName(arg0.getTestMethod());

    Reporter.log(textMsg, true);

}

// This will return method names to the calling function

private String returnMethodName(ITestNGMethod method) {

    return method.getRealClass().getSimpleName() + "." + method.getMethodName();

}
```

Answer (score 6):

From [the documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection):

```
public class LoginTest {

  @Test
  public void Test01_LoginPage() {
    //Some Code here
  }


  @Test
  public void Test02_LoginPage() {
    //Some Code Here
  }

  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeTestCase(Method m) {
    System.out.println(m.getName());
  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void AfterTestCase(Method m) {
    System.out.println(m.getName());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The below example explains how you can get the method name and class name of your @test method in before method and After method

```
@Test
public void exampleTest(){


}   


@BeforeMethod
        public  void  beforemethod(Method method){
//if you want to get the class name in before method
      String classname = getClass().getSimpleName();
//IF you want to get the method name in the before method 
      String methodName = method.getName() 
//this will return you   exampleTest   
        }

@AfterMethod
        public  void  beforemethod(Method method){
//if you want to get the class name in After method
      String classname = getClass().getSimpleName();
//IF you want to get the method name in the After method 
      String methodName = method.getName()  
//this will return you   exampleTest   

        }
```